# how to update picklist field according to another object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, batch, schedulebatch

I have two objects:

- `object1__c`, which has a text field called `sds__c` and a picklist field called `sds_chek__c` (values "Yes"/"No")
- `object2__c` contain a text field called `sds__c`

Here, I want to compare both objects' `sdc_c` values. If any records match, then in the `object1__c` picklist field populate with "Yes". If not match even one record also, the picklist value should populate with "No".

Please any one can help me!

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: Do you mean that, for example If value of sds_c = "text"(object1_c) and if there is any record containing "text" in object2_c then picklist field value on that record(object1_c) should be changed to "yes" ?

Comment: As pointed out already by Rahul, pls indicate the relationship between object1__c and object2__c

Comment: no relationship in between the objects both are different.

Comment: hi rahul yes that is my scenario what did u understand that is only

Comment: suppose object1 sds_c field contain the following records SDS114, SDS116, SDS189.

Comment: suppose object1 sds_c field contain the following records SDS114, SDS116, SDS189. and object2 sds_c field contain the following records SDS101,SDS110,SDS114 in both of them only one value is same in this time pick list value papup with 'Yes' reming two records pick list value papup with 'No'.

Comment: Question 1: how many objects (table rows) are involved - 100, 1000, 10,000 or more? Question 2: is this a once-off process or do you want this one automatically (e.g. in a trigger) when any sds__c field changes?

Answer (score 1):

How about trigger compare?
You must create 2 triggers make it work.

on object 2 you must have after insert/update (and before delete but I will skip it) actions in method:

```
Set<String> matchedFields = new Set<String>();
object_1__c[] obj1List = new object_1__c[]{};

for(object_2__c obj : Trigger.new){
    matchedFields.add(sds__c);
}

for(object_1__c obj : [SELECT Id, sds_chek__c
                       FROM object_1__c
                       WHERE sds__c IN : matchedFields]){

   if(obj.sds_chek__c == 'No'){
       obj.sds_chek__c = 'Yes';
       obj1List.add(obj)
   }
}

update obj1List;
```

You should also have trigger on before insert object_1__c that will check if in system already is some matching record

If you have any other question please let me know

Comment: thank you for giving reply. can we implement this same  senario in batch apex? if it is passble please let me know i have to impliment this code in batch class only

Comment: In Batch you can implement it, but mayby better idea would be to use Object1__c as base...  How many records each type you have?

Comment: 1000 records i have to upload into object1 every week on monday

Comment: how about object 2 - are those records deleted/created offten?

Comment: object2 data created

Comment: the below code i did write using triggers its working but same logic i have write in batch apex class how?            trigger rrr on Demand__c (before insert) {
    for(demand__c d:trigger.new){
         system.debug(d.rrd_number__c);
        list<idc_demand__c> b=[select id,rrd_number__c from idc_demand__c where rrd_number__C=:d.rrd_number__c];
    system.debug(b);
        if(b.size()==0){
          system.debug('no'); 
            d.idc_chek__c='No';
        }else{
            system.debug('yes');
            d.idc_chek__c='Yes';
        }
            
    }   
}

Comment: I am busy atm, but I will try create some code for you later